# How to find out Max<List<List>> in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'd like to find out largest sum of numbers separated by empty row. In this example I am looking to get number 6 (3+3)

```
1
1

2
2

3
3
```

Brute forcing this I would `=MAX(SUM(A1:A2),SUM(A4:A5),SUM(A7:A8))` which does the job but obviously not practical. How can I express above more elegantly without hardcoding anything?

Thinking out loud, I would like to

- Ingest all numbers, split by empty row into some kind of `List<List>`
- Iterate over this list, sum numbers in child list and pick a winner

How can this be done in Excel?

Comment: So is the number of entries in a given group fixed at 2, as in your example? If not, perhaps posting a more realistic example would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it, this is just one of them. In cell `C1` you can put the following formula:

```
=LET(set, A1:A9, matrix, 1*TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",
  FALSE, set),",,",";"),",",";", TRUE),m, COLUMNS(matrix), ones, SEQUENCE(m,1,,0),
  MAX(MMULT(matrix, ones))
)
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: The third input argument of `TEXTSPLIT` set to `TRUE` ensures you can have more than one empty row in the middle of the range. The second input argument of `TEXTJOIN` set to `FALSE` is required to ensure to generate of more than one comma (`,`), which is our condition to replace by the row delimiter (`;`) so we can split by row and columns. `MMULT` requires numbers and `TEXTSPLIT` converts the information into texts. we need to coerce the result into a number by multiplying it by `1`.

The formula follows the approach you suggested, you can test the intermediate step. Instead of having as output `MAX` result the variable you want to verify, for example:

```
=LET(set, A1:A9, matrix, 1*TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",
  FALSE, set),",,",";"),",",";", TRUE),m, COLUMNS(matrix), ones, SEQUENCE(m,1,,0),
  TMP, MAX(MMULT(matrix, ones)), matrix
)
```

will produce the following output:

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

An alternative to `MULT` is to use `BYROW` array function (less verbose):

```
=LET(set, A1:A8, matrix, 1*TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",
  FALSE, set),",,",";"),",",";", TRUE),MAX(BYROW(matrix, LAMBDA(m, SUM(m))))
)
```